# Edited: Let $I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin 2x)^{1/3}\sin x dx$ $J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos 2x)^{1/3}\cos x dx$. Find $I/J$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

Edit:Sorry guys I made an error in question, I have edited it now.
I found $$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin 2x)^{1/3}\sin x dx = 2^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\cos 2x)^{1/3}\cos x dx$$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\cos 2x)^{1/3}\cos xdx=2^{1/2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\sin 2x)^{1/3}\sin x dx$$
So I got them in each other's integral form but the limits have changed and I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Substitute $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$ in $I$ and see what happens. In general, $$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx.$$

Comment: As others have noted, the ratio is $1$. FWIW the common value of these integrals is $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{4/3}xdx=\tfrac12\operatorname{B}(7/6,\,1/2)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(7/6)}{2\Gamma(5/3)}$.

Comment: It seems the answers given so far have calculated the wrong integrand and the wrong integral. It's $(\sin 2 x)^{1/3}$, not $(\sin x)^{1/3}$

Comment: It seems that, differently from $ I$, a closed form for $J$ could probably not exist when the correct integrands are used. As explained in my answer, this depends on the presence of a hypergeometric function that cannot be transformed into elementary functions.

Comment: $\cos(2x)$ can be stricly negative when $x\in [0;\frac{\pi}{2}]$ (for example when $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, it's $-1$.

Comment: Yes, the negative portion of $\cos  2x$ in the range $\pi/4 \leq x \leq \pi/2$ is just the component whose integral seems not to have a closed form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both integrals can be determined by appropriate substitutions.  Starting from the first one, this is a plot of the function $y=\sin^{1/3} 2x \,\sin x$ in the range $0\leq x \leq\pi/2$:

[image]

The integral $I$ of this function can be written as

$$\displaystyle I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin 2x)^{1/3} \,\,\sin x \, dx\\
=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(2\sin x \cos x)^{1/3}\sin x \, dx \\
=2^{1/3}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{1/3} x \,\sin^{4/3} x\, dx  $$

Setting $t=\cos^2 x$ we have

$$x=\arccos(\sqrt{t})$$
$$dx=-\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t(1-t)}}$$

and then

$$I=-2^{1/3}\int_{1}^{0}\frac{t^{1/6}(1-t)^{2/3}}{  2(\sqrt{t(1-t)})  }\, dt \\
=  2^{-2/3}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/3}(1-t)^{1/6}\, dt$$

Now we can use the Euler integral representation of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)

$$\displaystyle _2F_1(a,b,c;z)\\= \frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(b)\Gamma(c-b)}\int _{0}^{1}\frac{t^{b-1}(1-t)^{c-b-1}}{(1-zt)^{a}}\,dt$$

Setting $a=-1/6$, $b=2/3$, $c=5/3$, and $z=1$ we have

$$I=2^{-2/3} \displaystyle \int _{0}^{1} t^{-1/3}(1-t)^{1/6}\,dt\\
=   \frac{\Gamma(2/3)}{\Gamma(5/3)}  \, _2F_1\left(-\frac 16,\frac 23,\frac 53;1\right)\\ $$

which gives, by the classical [closed-form formula](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/02/0001/) that expresses the hypergeometric function with argument $z=1$ in terms of [Gamma functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function),

$$I=2^{-2/3}\frac{\Gamma(2/3)\,\Gamma(7/6)}{\Gamma(11/6)}  \approx 0.841309... $$

in accordance with the [numerical value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dintegrate%20cuberoot%28sin%202x%29%20sin%20x%20dx%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi%2F2) given by WA for the initial integral $I$.

Interestingly, this result can be alternatively written, using some properties of the Gamma function, as

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3) }{10 \pi \, 2^{1/3}}  $$

---

Now let us consider the second integral. This is a plot of the function $y=\cos^{1/3} 2x \,\cos x$ in the range $0\leq x \leq\pi/2$:

[image]

It is worthy of note that, applying in this case the same approach, i.e. with a single substitution to directly calculate the integral in the whole range $0\leq x\leq \pi/2$, would require longer calculations as compared to those used for the first integral $I$ (as shown below, this mainly depends on the particular features of the negative component). So it is easier to calculate separately the positive (for $0\leq x \leq \pi/4$) and the negative component (for $\pi/4\leq x\leq\pi/2$) of the integral using different substitutions. By simplicity, I will call these two components $J_1$ and $J_2$, respectively.

The integral $J_1$ can be rewritten as

$$\displaystyle J_1=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\cos 2x)^{1/3}\cos 2x \, dx\\
=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(1-2\sin^2 x )^{1/3}\cos x \, dx $$

Setting $t= 2\sin^2 x$ we have

$$x=\arcsin \sqrt{\frac t2}$$
$$dx=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t(2-t)}}$$

and then

$$J_1=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-t)^{1/3}\sqrt{1-t/2}}{  2\sqrt{t(2-t)} }\, dt \\
=  2^{-3/2}\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{1/3}\, dt$$

Using again the above mentioned Euler integral representation of the hypergeometric function, setting $a=-1/3$, $b=1/2$, $c=3/2$, and $z=1$ we have

$$J_1=2^{-1} \displaystyle \int _{0}^{1} t^{-1/2}(1-t)^{1/3}\,dt\\
= 2^{-3/2}  \frac{\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(3/2)}  \, _2F_1\left(-\frac 13,\frac 12,\frac 32;1\right)\\ $$

which gives, by the closed-form formula the hypergeometric function with argument $z=1$,

$$J_1=2^{-3/2}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\,\Gamma(4/3)}{\Gamma(11/6)} \approx 0.594895... $$

confirming the [numerical value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dintegrate%20cuberoot%28cos%202x%29%20cos%20x%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi%2F4) of the integral $J_1$ provided by WA.

This can be alternatively written as

$$J_1=\frac{\sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3) }{10 \pi \,2^{5/6}} \,  $$

Note that $J_1=I/\sqrt{2}$, as already noted in the OP.

---

For the second component of $J$, we can write

$$\displaystyle J_2=  \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(\cos 2x)^{1/3} \cos x \, dx\\
 \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}(2\cos^2 x -1)^{1/3}\cos x \, dx $$

Setting $t= 2\cos^2 x $ we have

$$x=\arccos \sqrt{\frac t2}$$
$$dx=-\frac{dt}{2\sqrt{t(2-t)}}$$

and then

$$J_2=-\int_{1}^{0}\frac{(t-1)^{1/3}\sqrt{t/2}}{  2\sqrt{t(2-t)} }\, dt \\
=  -\frac 14 \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^{1/3}(1-t/2)^{-1/2}\, dt$$

Note that, compared to $I$ and $J_1$, in this case a term of the form $(1-zt)$ with $z=1/2$ occurs in the integral. Proceeding as above, using the Euler integral and setting $a=1/2$, $b=1$, $c=7/3$, and $z=1/2$, we have

$$J_2=-\frac 14 \displaystyle \int _{0}^{1} (1-t)^{1/3}(1-t/2)^{-1/2}\,dt\\
= - \frac{1}{4}  \, \frac{\Gamma(4/3)}{\Gamma(7/3)}  
 _2F_1\left(\frac 12,1,\frac 73;\frac 12\right)  $$

and since $\Gamma(4/3)\Gamma(7/3)=3/4$,

$$J_2=- \frac{3}{16}  \,
 _2F_1\left(\frac 12,1,\frac 73;\frac 12\right)  $$

As a result of the term $(1-zt)$ with $z=1/2$, the resulting hypergeometric function has $1/2$ as its last term as well. Unfortunately, I found no closed form for such hypergeometric function, whose numerical value is

$$ _2F_1\left(\frac 12,1,\frac 73;\frac 12\right)  \approx 1.1418005... $$

Calling $H$ this value, we have

$$J_2=- \frac{3}{16} H \,  \approx 0.214087...$$

Thus, the second integral $J$ is

$$J=J_1+J_2\\
=\frac{\sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3) }{10 \pi \,2^{5/6}}  -   \frac{3}{16} H \, \\ \approx 0.594895-0.214087  \approx 0.380808... $$

in accordance with the [numerical value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dintegrate%20cuberoot%28cos%202x%29%20cos%20x%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi%2F2) of $J$ given by WA.

---

Collecting all these results, we have that

$$\frac IJ=\frac{\sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3) /(10 \pi \,2^{1/3}) }{  
  \sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3) /(10 \pi \,2^{5/6})  -   3H/16   }\\
=  \frac{2^{8/3}\sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3) }{  2^{13/6}
  \sqrt{3} \,\,  \Gamma^3(1/3)  - 15\pi H } \approx 2.209274...$$

confirming the [estimate of the ratio](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28integral%20cuberoot%28sin%202x%29%20sin%20x%20dx%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi%2F2%29%2F%28integral%20cuberoot%28cos%202x%29%20cos%20x%20dx%2C%20x%3D0%20to%20pi%2F2%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)  given by WA.

---

As a final note it should be pointed out that, if the second integral had bounds  $-\pi/4 \leq x\leq \pi/4$ (thus including the whole positive portion of the integral existing in the range of $x$ from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$, with no negative components), the final result would be considerably simpler. In this case, as a result of the symmetry of the function $y=(\cos 2x)^{1/3}\cos x$ with respect to the $y$-axis, we would have $J=2J_1$ and then

$$\frac{I}{J}=\frac{I}{2J_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the image of $(\sin x)^{4/3}$ and $(\cos x)^{4/3}$, you will find $(\sin x)^{4/3}=(\cos (\pi/2-x))^{4/3}$, so

\begin{equation*}
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x)^{4/3}\;dx=-\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^0(\cos x)^{4/3}\;dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}(\cos x)^{4/3}\;dx
\end{equation*}

Finally, we have the result that $I/J=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Both the integrals can be expessed via [the Beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) $\operatorname B(a,b)$
and [incomplete Beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) $\operatorname B(z,a,b).$

\begin{align}
&I=\int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sqrt[3]{\sin 2x}\,\sin x\,\mathrm dx
=-\int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sqrt[3]{2\sin x\cos x}\,\mathrm d\cos x
=\int\limits_0^1\sqrt[\large3]{2y\mathstrut}\,\sqrt[\large6]{1-y^2}\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int\limits_0^1\dfrac{\sqrt[\large6]{1-y^2}}{\sqrt[\large3]{4y^2}}\,\mathrm d(y^2)
=\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]4}\int\limits_0^1z^{\large-\,^1/_3}(1-z)^{\large ^1/_6}\,\mathrm dz
=\dfrac1{\sqrt[3]4}\operatorname B\left(\frac23,\frac76\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt\pi}2\,\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{11}{6}\right)}\approx 0.84130\,92631\,95273,\\[4pt]
&J=\int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sqrt[3]{\cos 2x}\,\cos x\,\mathrm dx
=\int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sqrt[3]{1-2\sin^2 x}\,\,\mathrm d\sin x
=\int\limits_0^1\sqrt[\large3]{1-2y^2}\,\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int\limits_0^1\frac{\sqrt[\large3]{1-2y^2}}{4y}\,\mathrm d(2y^2)
=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\int\limits_0^2z^{\large\,-^1/_2}|1-z|^{\large^1/_3}\,\mathrm dz
=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\left(\operatorname B\left(\frac12,\frac43\right)-J_1\right),\\[4pt]
&J_1 = \int\limits_1^2z^{\large\,-^1/_2}(z-1)^{\large^1/_3}\,\mathrm dz
=\left|\,t=\dfrac {z-1}{z},\,z=\dfrac 1{1-t},\,\mathrm dz=\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{(1-t)^2}\,\right|\\
&=\int\limits_0^{\large^1/_2}(1-t)^{\large^1/_2}\left(\dfrac t{1-t}\right)^{\large^1/_3}\,
\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{(1-t)^2}
=\int\limits_0^{\large^1/_2}t^{\large^1/_3}\,(1-t)^{\large \,-^{11}/_6}\,\mathrm dt
=\operatorname B\left(\frac12,\frac43,-\frac56\right),\\
&J=\dfrac1{2\sqrt2}\left(\operatorname B\left(\frac12,\frac43\right)-\operatorname B\left(\frac12,\frac43,-\dfrac56\right)\right)\approx 0.38080\,78819\,80045,\\[4pt]
\end{align}

However, [required ratio](http://%5Coperatorname%20B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac12,%5Cfrac53%5Cright)+%5Coperatorname%20B%5Cleft(%5Cfrac12,%5Cfrac53%5Cright))
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\dfrac IJ = 2^{\large^5/_6}\dfrac{\operatorname B\left(\frac23,\frac76\right)} {\operatorname B\left(\frac12,\frac43\right)-\operatorname B\left(\frac12,\frac43,-\frac56\right)} \approx 2.20927\,48154\,81256}}$$
can not be essentially simplified.